# How to change existing attribute in a field

Tags: xml, odoo-10, odoo, kanban

I have this kanban view that has this attribute:

```
default_group_by="stage_id"
```

I want to inherit this view and change this attribute with another variable

```
default_group_by="state"
```

Now I know how to add/replace a field or add an attribute, but is it possible to replace an attribute? 
Thanks.

Comment: Use `<field name="x" position="attributes">` and inside `<attribute name="default_group_by">state</attribute>`. Then don't forget to close the `field` tag.

Comment: Ok. Can you explain to me what happens exactly? How odoo will behave? He will replace the existing attribute value with the new value? Why? isn't he going to be confused with the same attribute with 2 values?

Comment: The attribute is going to be replaced. The old value is removed and yours is the new value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this you can replace the attribute value of a field in odoo:

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='your-field-name-here']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="default_group_by">state</attribute>
</xpath>
```